# A functional with certain property

Tags: functional-analysis

Show that for every $x \in X$ exists $f \in X^*$ such that $f(x) = ||x||$ and $||f|| = 1$.

Could someone give me some hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Use the [Hahn-Banach extension Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem).

**More precise hints:**

- You want that $\|f\| = 1$, and so you need $\color{red}{|f(y)|\leq \|y\|}$ for every $y \in X$. Since $f(x)=\|x\|$ this will imply $\|f\|=1$ (do you see why?).
- Note that $y \mapsto \|y\|$ is a $\color{red}{\text{sublinear}}$ function.
- Finally you may first define a linear function $\tilde{f}: U \to \Bbb K$ on the subspace $\color{red}{U = \{\alpha x \mid \alpha \in \Bbb K\}}$ and then extend it by the Theorem.

Can you find $\tilde{f}$?

Comment: Is this hint enlightening enough or you need more details?

Comment: Could you give me more details please?

Comment: @stolikp Is it more clear now?

Comment: Is it $\bar{f}(\alpha x) = |\alpha|\cdot||x||$?

Comment: @stolikp almost :), this function is not linear but $\tilde{f}(\alpha x) = \alpha \|x\|$ is linear.

Comment: One more question. We have $\bar{f}(\alpha x) = \alpha||x|| \leq p(\alpha x) = |\alpha|\cdot||x||$. When we extend $\bar{f}$ to $f$ we get $f(x) \leq p(x) = ||x||$. But I have to be sure that $f(x) = ||x||$. How can I be sure?

Comment: @stolikp $|f(y)|\leq \|y\|$ for every $y$ ensures $\|f\| \leq 1$ and $|f(x)| = \|x\|$ ensures $\|f\| \geq 1$